# pgAdmin III Import sql Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I am having trouble importing a database (19 tables) from MySQL into Postgresql. I used MySQL Workbench Migration tool to save my DB in a dump file. Also, these tables have relationships.

When I use psql command prompt to import `[\i 'C:/.../dump']` I get.

1.

> ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "foreign_key_checks"

2.

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "'" (for every table CREATE TABLE)

I am not a programmer, so thank you if this is an easy fix. The reason I am trying to migrate this database, is just to learn how it's done.

Comment: You can't just restore a MySQL dump to a PostgreSQL instance. If only. Search for "migrate MySQL to PostgreSQL" to learn more.

Comment: [How to make a proper migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_proper_migration_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL)

Comment: http://pgloader.io/howto/mysql.html